# Android Database SQLite cannot be deleted even the return is not zero

Tags: android, sqlite

SQLite Android cannot be deleted, However, when I delete it, the return value is > 0.

```
public int delete(Uri uri, String whereClause, String[] whereValues) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        String finalWhere;
        int deletedRowsCount = 0;

        // Perform the delete based on URI pattern
        db.beginTransaction();
        try {
            switch (uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
                case ALL:
                    // Delete return > 0
                    int deletedRowsCounts = db.delete(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.TABLE_NAME, null, null);
                    break;
                // If the incoming URI is invalid, throws an exception.
                default:
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unknown URI " + uri);
            }
        } finally {
            db.endTransaction();
        }

        // Notify observers of the the change
        getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(uri, null);

        // Returns the number of rows deleted.
        return deletedRowsCount;
    }
```

I tried to delete the catalogue table using the function above. It actually returns the row affected larger than zero. However, when I check the database, i still have the data.

I call the delete from here (below)

```
private void updateContentProvider(RestMethodResult<CatalogueList> result) {
    CatalogueList catalogues = result.getResource();
    if(catalogues == null) {
        return;
    }
    List<Catalogue> listCatalogue = catalogues.getCatalogues();

    if(listCatalogue.size() != 0) {
        mContext.getContentResolver().delete(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.CONTENT_URI, null, null);
        Cursor cursor = mContext.getContentResolver().query(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.CONTENT_URI, null,null,null,null);
        //i still have all the data, i confirm it using this log
        Log.i(CatalogueProcessor.class.getSimpleName(), cursor.getCount() + "");
        cursor.close();
    }

    for(Catalogue catalogue : listCatalogue) {
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.id, catalogue.getId());
        values.put(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.name, catalogue.getName());
        values.put(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.object_path, catalogue.getObjectPath());
        values.put(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.thumbnail_path, catalogue.getThumbnailPath());

        byte[] thumbnailBytes = FileHelper.getBytesFromURLAdminServer(catalogue.getThumbnailPath());
        values.put(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.thumbnail, thumbnailBytes );

        byte[] objectBytes = FileHelper.getBytesFromURLAdminServer(catalogue.getObjectPath());
        values.put(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.object, objectBytes);

        mContext.getContentResolver().insert(CatalogueProviderContract.CatalogueTable.CONTENT_URI,
                values);


    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing the delete inside a transaction, but you don't call `setTransactionSuccessful()` before `endTransaction()`, so it gets rolled back.

Comment: omg, i forgot about it, thanks bro, u can set it as an answer

Comment: No problem. Actually, I'll just mark this as a duplicate, since it's a common issue. Thanks, though. Glad you got it working. Cheers!